# Android - Uploading a file to a java servlet and using Apache IOUtils to handle it

Tags: java, android, servlets, file-upload

i'm using the following tutorial to upload a file in Android:

http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

On the server side I use Java servlets with Apache IOUtils to handle it.

```
ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator fileItemIterator = fileUpload.getItemIterator(request);
while (fileItemIterator.hasNext()) {
  FileItemStream filestream = fileItemIterator.next();
  doStuff(filestream);
}
```

In the browser everything works fine, but on Android my problem is that when I call getContentType on a filestream, it returns null.
Why are the differences here? I'm not handling the null value of getContentType because something tells me is not ok to be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Wireshark to view what was the browser actually sending.
It seams that (among other stuff), another Content-Type header is sent (in the "MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation" section), after Content-Disposition (for ex. "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n".
So, in the file upload tutorial, after the following line:

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"uploadedfile\";" + "filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

I just added:

```
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + mimeType + lineEnd);
```

Now it seams the uploading process is working fine.

Of course, for many extensions, mimeType will probably be null, so it should be checked, according to needs.